# Обработчик корзины товаров на JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, корзина

Есть сайт-магазин с корзиной товаров реализованной на jquery, товары туда падают и цена считается, все пишется в переменные, но не могу перекинуть эти данные на другую страницу для оформления и скинуть с сайта на почту или сервер. Нагуглил что через ajax это делается но не знаю как, пните пожалуйста в нужную сторону где копать или инфу какую нибудь полезную, заранее благодарен.

Comment: Если всё считается на стороне клиента это как минимум не безопасно, лучше считать всё на стороне сервера и там же сохранять, тогда проблема с потерей данных сама решиться.

Comment: На стороне клиента добавление в корзину и ввод своих данных, далее эти данные должны улетать на сервер и обрабатываться. Я просто не знаю как их на сервер перекинуть, что есть сам сервер (корзину по уроку делал на ютюбе там был указан просто скрипт пхп, сам урок обрезан) и как мне их обратно вернуть на сайт что бы показать клиенту что он купил.
Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Вернуть обратно просто отдав на страницу переменные php и сохранить их как js переменные или вставить сразу в html, а потом через js их собрать снова, сложно так сказать, по идее всё в уроке должно быть, лучше найдите более понятный урок